How do I target arm64, excluding x86_64, in flutter run -d macos?
flutter run -d chrome runs with no issues, but -d macos triggers the following warning. I'm on arm64, and am happy compiling during development for just arm64. How do I target arm64 alone?
flutter run -d macos
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006000-0008299F2229401E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006000-0008299F2229401E }
Building macOS application...


Why the downvote? Please add a comment.

When they don't say it's often just someone that gets off on downvoting.

Apparently setting the flags directly on the flutter run command no longer is an option, so you'll have to set the EXCLUDED_ARCHS manually. There are quite a few ways to do this, so I'll give you a couple of simple options:

Edit the Podfile in your project:
 post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=macos*]"] = "x86_64"
     end
   end
 end

Then pod install

Directly edit the project.pbxproj:


Modify your macos/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. Look for the EXCLUDED_ARCHS build setting and set it to x86_64.
As far as I know EXCLUDED_ARCHS is the only way to build for one particular architecture. You could poke around the file here, although that is not specific the the flutter run command.

This sounds exactly right, but something is off. Also googling for "FLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM_ARCH" doesn't bring up anything, which suggests there is a typo. Can you double-check?

Probably not an option now; see edit.
